# ProcessBuilder on Mac

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, processbuilder

I have problems in using ProcessBuilder on mac.

When I execute this on windows it works, but on mac not. 
in the arguments, you have to put the path of the program

How i can use this kind of codes on Mac??

I use eclipse and this is the code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class RunProcess {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, Exception {
    if (args.length <= 0) {
        System.err.println("Se necesita un programar a ejecutar");

        System.exit(-1);

    }
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(args);
    try {
        Process process = pb.start();
        int retorno = process.waitFor();
        System.out.println("La ejecucion de" + Arrays.toString(args) + "devuelve" + retorno);

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.err.println("Excepcion de E/S");
        System.exit(-1);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        System.err.println("El proceso hijo finalizó de forma incorrecta");
        System.exit(-1);

    }
  }
}
```

Stack trace:

```
"/Users/JeysonMerino/Applications/Applications/headsoccer.app": error=13, Permission denied
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at LanzarProcesos.ejecutar(LanzarProcesos.java:8)
    at LanzarProcesos.main(LanzarProcesos.java:16)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=13, Permission denied
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:247)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
```

Comment: what happens when you run it on a Mac?

Comment: What is the error you are getting while running on Mac? What are the parameters you are passing while running the application?

Comment: I ran your code, adding this line at the start of the method: `args = new String[]{"ls"};` so that it would try to run the `ls` command. It ran and printed this output: `La ejecucion de[ls]devuelve0`.

Comment: When i run, he enter in the try catch and show "exception E/S"

Comment: In the arguments i enter the path of the program that i want open.

Comment: Please edit your post and add the complete command that you run, and how you run it. For example, "To run it, I open a new terminal, `cd ~/MyJavaProject`, and then `java RunProcess ls -l`"

Comment: This code work to open a program. And u have to put the path on the arguments to open the program.

Comment: I run this on a archive.java, and i pick on run as Java Aplication on Eclipse

Comment: Open the [Run Configurations](https://imgur.com/tllCfl4) window and click on the _Show Command Line_ button. This will display the [Command Line](https://imgur.com/RVMtqTi) window. Copy the entire command and add it to your question.

Comment: Exceptions are extremely valuable for indicating what went wrong and why. Remove your try/catch entirely, and let the exceptions propagate.  This will allow you (and us) to see the full stack trace of the exception that’s occurring.

Comment: when i remove it: i get this "/Users/JeysonMerino/Applications/Applications/headsoccer.app": error=13, Permission denied
 at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
 at LanzarProcesos.ejecutar(LanzarProcesos.java:8)
 at LanzarProcesos.main(LanzarProcesos.java:16)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=13, Permission denied
 at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
 at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:247)
 at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
 at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)

Comment: “Permission denied” suggests that you don’t have permission to execute that file.

Comment: @Abra /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_111.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /Users/JeysonMerino/eclipse-workspace/PSPs/bin RunProcess /Applications/Mahjong Solitaire Epic.app/Contents/MacOS/Mahjong Solitaire Epic